# getting error while hitting an API in postman

Tags: typescript, postman, nestjs

am getting error of 404 not found while hitting the API in postman.

{
    "statusCode": 404,
    "message": "Cannot PUT /crud?id=5e824c8cbfc332566cf10c56",
    "error": "Not Found"
}

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct method? Maybe it's POST, not PUT.

Comment: yes am using correct method

Comment: Please post the code of your Nest.js route.

Comment: @Put(':id')
    update(@Param('id')id:string,@Body()datamodel:studentmodel){
        return this.crudservice.update(id,datamodel)
    }

Comment: Try `/crud/5e824c8cbfc332566cf10c56` instead of `/crud?id=5e824c8cbfc332566cf10c56`. If that doesn't work, post the entire code of your controller.

Comment: updated in my question.Please check

Comment: Is that the entire file? It looks like you posted code from two different files.

Comment: yes am posted code from two different files.

Comment: one is controller code and another one in service

Comment: Can you post the entire contents of those two files?

Comment: here is the link of my repo https://github.com/salil20495/crud_api

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you have posted via GitHub, you should be making requests to `http://localhost:5000/crid/<id>` whatever that id may be. If you are still getting 404s, check a couple of things

1) have you rebuilt **and** restarted your server (running `npm run start:dev` should do this is a Nest project)

2) add in a simple logger that shows what is being requested

3) Read through your dist and start logs to ensure that the route is setup as you expect